# WSL: Windows only able to access localhost hosted by apache2 a moment after a reboot

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After a Windows reboot, I tried to run `sudo service apache2 start`, and in Windows browser, I was able to access localhost for a moment. After awhile, I can't access it anymore. A refresh on the page doesn't load the index.html.

I'm running Windows 1903, any idea why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Some information is required, error messages, Apache log etc. And why use Apache in WSL when it can run on Windows?

Comment: Are you using WSL1 or WSL2 ?